# Is there a simple interpretation I' in which these are all false?

Tags: first-order-logic

The axioms of Q are extra-logical assertions true in the intended interpretation I^A of elementary arithmetic. Consider the first three axioms:
Q1: ∀x∀y(x′ = y′ → x = y),     Q2: ∀x o ≠ x′,     Q3: ∀x(x ≠ o → ∃y x = y′)
Is there a simple alternative interpretation I' in which they are all false?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - consider the natural numbers with the symbol "$0$" interpreted as usual and the function $'$ interpreted as $$x'=0$$ for all $x$. This violates all three rules at once.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Huh? Q3 says every nonzero thing has a predecessor. In this model, $0$ is the only thing which does have a predecessor.

Comment: so does it means that the interpretation is empty set?